# Al compilar de nuevo el proyecto desaparecen archivos speechrecognicer

Tags: android, clase, google-cloud-platform

cuando recompilo mi programa, desaparece todo el contenido de una carpeta que está en el generated, y no se como hacer para que no lo haga ya que sin esas clases, no puedo ejecutar el programa. y me sale esto:

```
com/google/cloud/android/speech/SpeechService.kt    
Unresolved reference: speech    
Unresolved reference: speech    
Unresolved reference: speech    
Unresolved reference: speech    
Unresolved reference: speech    
Unresolved reference: speech    
Unresolved reference: speech    
Unresolved reference: speech    
Unresolved reference: SpeechGrpc    
Unresolved reference: StreamingRecognizeResponse    
Unresolved reference: StreamingRecognizeResponse    
Unresolved reference: RecognizeResponse 
Unresolved reference: RecognizeResponse 
Unresolved reference: StreamingRecognizeRequest 
Unresolved reference: RecognitionConfig 
Unresolved reference: StreamingRecognizeRequest 
Unresolved reference: RecognitionConfig 
Unresolved reference: StreamingRecognizeRequest 
Unresolved reference: RecognitionConfig 
Unresolved reference: RecognitionAudio  
Unresolved reference: RecognitionConfig 
Unresolved reference: RecognitionAudio
```

Quiero saber y entender por que se me borran y como hacer para que cuando le de a compilar de nuevo el proyecto. No me borre esta carpeta o me la genera directamente.

Comment: Estas instalando y configurando bien el `JDK` y `JRE` de java? y configurado correctamente las variables de entorno? vi un error parecido una vez y fue por que instalo y configuro `Android Studio` primero sin instalar el `JDK` y `JRE` de java, quizás no sea tu caso pero puedes revisar esto.

Comment: Cual es la configuración de build.gradle?

Comment: @DavidVillegas era problema de dependencias, arreglado (aunque super dificil encontrarlas, no estaban ni mvrepository)